# change thickness median line geom_boxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to do some modifications of a geom_boxplot(). Because my boxplots are really "small" sometimes (see yellow and green clade in the graphic [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnki63b7bofvz8b/boxplot.png)) i want to highlight the median even more. so is it possible to adjust the thickness of the median line?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This solution is not obvious from the documentation, but luckily does not require us to edit the source code of `ggplot2`. After digging through the source of `ggplot2` I found that the thickness of the median line is controlled by the `fatten` parameter. By default `fatten` has a value of two:

```
require(reshape)
require(ggplot2)
cars_melt = melt(cars)

ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value), data = cars_melt) + 
  geom_boxplot(fatten = 2)
```

[image]

But if we increase the value to for example 4, the median line becomes thicker.

```
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value), data = cars_melt) + 
  geom_boxplot(fatten = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: How does the width of the median line relate to `lwd`? Is it a multiplier of whatever is specified for `lwd`, or is it a measurement of its own?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, changing `fatten` to a value less than 2 will make it thinner--helpful when your bars are really small and the median line is taking up most of the bar.