# change thickness of the whole line geom_boxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to increase the boldness of the entire boxplot to be more visible on the hard copy. from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475865/change-thickness-median-line-geom-boxplot) seems "fatten" parameter change the thickness of the only median line. Is there any other parameter that control the thickness/width of the the whole box plot ?

```
require(reshape)
require(ggplot2)
cars_melt = melt(cars)

ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value), data = cars_melt) + 
  geom_boxplot(fatten = 2)
```

Comment: `geom_boxplot(lwd=3)`  ("lwd" for "line width"). Also, if `lwd` makes the median too thick, you can use `lwd` and `fatten` together to make the median line thinner relative to the other lines.

Comment: omg ! probably because it was that easy, nobody has asked this question before !

Comment: I'm not sure anything about `R` is easy the first time around.

Comment: @eipi10 Might as well add that as an answer, no?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `geom_boxplot(lwd=3)` ("lwd" for "line width"). Also, if `lwd` makes the median too thick, you can use `lwd` and `fatten` together to make the median line thinner relative to the other lines.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note from the future, 2023... it is now `geom_boxplot(linewidth = 3)`